# internet connection issue after installing ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, system-installation

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 on a HP labtop. The installation process was finished successfully. I also enabled the wireless internet, the wireless icon shows the wireless connection is established. I checked both "enable networking" and "enable wi-fi". However, the ping command such as "ping google.com" returns that `ping: unknown host google.com`.  the Firefox browser does not work either.

May I know how to fix this issue? thanks.

For your reference, please see the command command output as follows:

```
**ip a s**

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 64:51:06:ff:df:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether b0:10:41:d3:2d:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.92/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlo1
   valid_lft 86294sec preferred_lft 86294sec
inet6 fe80::aa57:46a1:fbb9:7689/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


**ping 8.8.8.8**
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=204 ttl=53 time=1093 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8  icmp_seq=350 ttl=53 time=61.3 ms

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by   resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
      nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Comment: Sounds like DNS is not working. Can you edit the question to include the full in- and output of `ip a s`, `ping 8.8.8.8` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Hi Henrik, the output has been updated in my original post

Comment: output from `ip a s` is badly formatted.

Comment: Does it look better now? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ping output shows that the network connection actually works, and that it's just DNS, and that's not surprising given the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`. Now that says that's it's generated by resolvconf, I've tried to use that, but never got to terms with it, so I'm probably not the best to give advice. The right thing to do is to figure out what should supply some useable DNS resolvers to resolvconf and make it do so.

A workaround is to uninstall resolvconf and manually put some DNS servers into `/etc/resolv.conf`. Your ISP probably has some, that they told you about when you became a customer. There are also some freely available, google has some if you don't care letting them know a lot about where you go online, there's OpenDNS which have been know to fake results, and the one I use censurfridns.dk (disclaimer: I know the guy who runs that).